# Decorator magic for REST services

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, decorator

I am looking all over the web for a library that offers decorator magic to easily create REST services for TypeScript. Like `@GET(`), `@PATH("/hello")` etc.

I am using [TypeORM](https://typeorm.io/) and [TypeGraphQL](https://typegraphql.com/) which both are fantastic. But I can not find a good option for REST services. I was looking at [typescript-rest](https://d0whc3r.github.io/typescript-rest/) but it has restrictions in it's Security decorator that is not working for me. It also has limitation in its folder structure to create routes.

What are you using? Any favorites?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using [nestjsx/crud](https://github.com/nestjsx/crud)

It's a goofd mix of nestjsx and typeorm